# How can I install netbeans 8.2 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have a downloaded file of netbeans8.2 but I get this error when I try to run it:

```
rohit@rohit-Vostro-15-3568:~$ ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh 
bash: ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please make sure when you ask a question to provide more clear details of it. go through some tips over here https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, where is the ` netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`  file located?

Comment: you probably need to `cd Downloads` first

Comment: they are downloaded and stored in my downloads folder. but unable to install them from terminal. please tell me about that.

Comment: navigate to the downloads folder as @Zanna said above, `cd Downloads` then make the file executable by doing `chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh` then run the file `./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`

Comment: it show permission denied

Comment: then do `sudo chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`

Comment: nothing happens. tell me the procedure from starting. how i can download  it and install again using terminal ony.

Comment: @LokeshSharma, you have to be in the same folder as the `netbeans-8.2-linux.sh` to run `chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`

Comment: ummmm sorry bro. i just do some mistake fwhile running arduino step. now it starts. and thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the recipe of installing any bash script file

`cd /path/to/scriptfile`
   `chmod +x script.sh` or `sudo chmod +x script.sh #for providing root privileges`
    `./script.sh`

So what you need to do is

open the terminal

Then navigate to the folder where your script is located which is downloads folder by doing

```
cd Downloads
```

Next is making your file executable by doing

```
sudo chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Then run the script by doing

```
./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

And everything will work fine, else you have another problem which you should tell us then or add any error message you get to your question if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. First off open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, this will place you in your `home` directory from where you will run the steps below.
2. Move that file with `nautilus` or with the following command to you `home` directory:

   ```
   find ~/Downloads -type f -iname netbeans-8.2-linux.sh -exec mv {} ~/ \;
   ```
3. Make sure you completed the download for `netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`:

   - get it here: https://netbeans.org/downloads/
4. Make sure it moved with this check if you used the terminal to move it:

   ```
   ls | grep netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```

   - Make sure you see the file name in the output result.
5. Check if you own the file with:

   ```
   ls -l netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```

   - The result should be like so:

     ```
     -rw-------   1 george george  119267328 Apr 23  2016 netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x64.sh
     ```
6. Make sure it's executable with:

   ```
   chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```
7. Then run it

   ```
   ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```